# plsql における procedure as begin end の文法を理解したい

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

現在plsqlを勉強しています。

以下のような文法が現場のSQLであったのですが、どこかにリファレンスなどございますでしょうか？

```
procedure プロシージャ名
(
    引数
)
as 
    メンバ変数のようなもの
begin 
    処理
end
```

それこそ何となくわかるような気はしますが、私が知っている文法は以下です。

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE   
    ストアドプロシージャ名[(引数名 {IN | OUT | INOUT} データ型,...)] 
IS   
    宣言部 
BEGIN   
    処理部 
EXCEPTION   
    例外処理部 
END ;
```

これに比べるとCREATEが省略されていたり、ISでなくASであったりしています。

少し何をリソースとして前者のような文法があり得るのかを知りたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原典のOracleのドキュメントを検索してみることをお勧めしておきます。

---

[Procedure Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/procedure_declaration.htm#i35564)
(最新の[Oracle 19c用ドキュメント](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/procedure-declaration-and-definition.html#GUID-9A48D7CE-3720-46A4-B5CA-C2250CA86AF2)では
`procedure_definition`に変わってますが、こっちの方が見やすかったので10g用から引用。)

(中略)

> Note that the procedure declaration in a PL/SQL block or package is not the same as creating a procedure in SQL. For information on the CREATE PROCEDURE SQL statement, see Oracle Database SQL Reference.

(中略)

> procedure declaration ::=
> [image: illustration procedure_declaration]

---

[14.11 CREATE PROCEDURE Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54)

(中略)

> create_procedure ::=
> [image: illustration create_procedure]

> plsql_procedure_source ::=
> [image: plsql_procedure_source]

---

前者の方は、プログラミング言語としてのPL/SQLでの手続宣言(手続定義)、後者はストアドPL/SQLを定義するためのSQL文、と言うことになりますね。相互に埋め込めるためあまり厳密に区別してもかえってわかりにくいかもしれませんが。
　キーワードの大文字小文字は区別しない、`AS`, `IS`はどちらでも良い、というのは両者共通です。

手続宣言(手続定義)はPL/SQLでの「宣言部」(あなたの前者の例での「メンバ変数のようなもの」)に書くことができます。

Comment: as,isどちらでもいいのですね。ありがとうございます。ドキュメントも確認いたします